# Recursive function that returns unique items from list [Common Lisp]

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm new Lisp programmer and need some help.

Given a list, I`m trying to copy elements that appear once in another list.

I have done the following:

```
(defun Unique-elements ( l uniqueList )
  (or (null l)
      (and (not (member (car l) (cdr l)))
           (Unique-elements (cdr l)))))
```

The function returns True if the supplied list contains distinct items. How to copy the distinct items in `uniqueList` and show it.

Example:

Given List:

```
(1 2 3 4 4 5 6 6 7 8 8 8 8)
```

Expected Result:

```
(1 2 3 5 7)
```

Comment: Your function does not work. You have two parameters `l`and `unique-list`. `unique-list` is unused. You call the function recursively with one argument, even though it expects two.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Yeah you are right. The problem is that I don't know how to store in the second parameter `unique-list` unique elements from `l`.

Answer (score 4):

That would be a working function for the original problem:

```
(defun has-only-unique-elements-p (l)
  (or (null l)
      (and (not (member (car l) (cdr l)))
           (has-only-unique-elements-p (cdr l)))))
```

If you want to return the unique elements you need to write it differently. A naive algorithm:

- if `l` is empty return `NIL`
- if the first element is in the rest list, remove the element and call the function recursively
- otherwise cons the first element to the result of the recursive call with the rest list

Comment: Note that the algorithm is quadratic (`O(len(l)^2)`); using hash tables reduces the asymptotic time to linear (`O(len(l))`).

Comment: @sds: good point, but he struggles with the basics of Lisp. ;-)

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to store in the second parameter `unique-list` unique elements from `l`

Comment: @IonLica: why would you need such a parameter?

Comment: @IonLica: why is it a requirement and what advantage would it give you?